# What is the tax levied against stock portion cashed out of 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, capital-gains-tax

I need some help, I'm having a surprisingly difficult time getting an answer to my question. I will be cashing out the stock portion of a previous employer's 401k, I need to know what sort of tax (and penalty) to expect.

I think I will be taxed long term capital gains on the appreciation, but not on the basis. This is from an employer from 4 years ago. I can't get a straight answer on this, even from my (soon to be previous...) tax person.

I suspect I will also get hit with the 10% penalty. But what number will the 10% be calculated against? The NUA? The total value of shares? The basis?

So if the NUA is $60k, I assume I would have to pay $18k in tax if my cap-gains rate is 20%, right? That's $12k for capital gains, $6k for penalty.

Also, I'm using this to buy the property my wife runs her business from. Will that use allow me to avoid some tax or penalty? I've read some things online regarding using retirement funds for the purchase of a first home, which this isn't.

Comment: A 401k is funded with pre-tax dollars, therefore all distributions are taxed as ordinary income, plus a 10% penalty if not qualified. Unlike a Roth IRA where you can withdraw contributions at any point without tax/penalty.

Comment: How much is pretax 401K contribution? how much is Roth contribution? How much is company contribution that has vested?

Answer (score 2):

You pay tax on the entire amount, not just the capital gains.

When cashing out such a plan you would pay the top marginal tax rate on the full amount plus another 10% in penalties.  It is very likely that the additional income, of the balance withdrawal, will increase your top marginal rate.

It is impossible to come up with a precise answer as we don't know the following:

- US Tax policy for 2017 (or any other year in the future)
- The state of your tax forms without this distribution
- The amount of your current 401K.

However, you can take a concept away from this that is important:  You will be taxed and penalized on the entire 401K balance, not just the capital gain.

In the "best case" scenario, that is you had little or no income in a given year.  Under current tax law you would owe about 31% of your 401K balance in taxes.  As this is such an inefficient use of money most authors recommend against it except in the case of extreme circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Withdrawals from a traditional 401(k) plan are always treated as cash income and the taxable portion is taxed at ordinary income tax rates, even if the money was held in stocks within the 401(k) plan and the amount withdrawn is equal to whatever capital gains you made by selling the stock within the 401(k) plan. If your plan permits you to take the distribution as stock shares (transferred to your taxable brokerage account), then, *for tax purposes,* it is treated as if you took a distribution of cash equal to the market price of the shares as of the day of the distribution and promptly bought the same number of shares in your brokerage account.  And yes, if the 401(k) plan assets in your ex-employer's plan consists solely of pretax contributions and the earnings thereon, then the entire distribution is ordinary taxable income regardless of whether you sold the stock within the 401(k) plan or took a distribution of stock from the plan and promptly (or after a few days) sold it. The capital gains or losses (if any) from such a sale are, of course, outside the 401(k) plan and taxable accordingly.

Finally, the 10% penalty for premature withdrawal from a traditional 401(k) will also apply if you are not 59.5 years of age or older (or maybe 55 since you are separated from service), and it will be computed on the entire distribution.